# Fielding numbers using < and > values

Tags: python

So i wish to field these numbers into groups as you can see below, the and is incorrect and wish to know the correct method of doing so.

After the "if" the code it assigns the a rating that co-incides with the score and then 1 is added to a counter that counts the number of groups with that rating.

```
#determining the meal rating and counting number of applied ratings and priniting
def mealrating(score):
    for x in range(0,len(score)):


        if 1 < and score[x] >3:
            review[x] = poor
            p = p + 1

        if 4 < and score[x] >6:
            review[x] = good
            g = g + 1


        if 7 < and score[x] >10:
            review[x] = excellent
            e = e + 1

print('\n')
print('%10s' % ('Poor:', p ))
print('%10s' % ('Good', g ))
print('%10s' % ('Excellent', e ))
```

Comment: what are u comparing 1 with ?? may b try 
`if score[x] > 1 and score[x] < 3:`

Comment: yes thanks ,silly me x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
if 1 < and score[x] >3:
```

just doesn't work. `and` connects two expressions, so this reads like

```
if (1 <) and (score[x] > 3):
```

And `1 <` is just meaningless.

A quick fix is

```
if 1 < score[x] and score[x] > 3:
```

But that looks like you didn't mean that -- after all, it checks whether score[x] is both greater than 1 and greater than 3, which is redundant. You probably meant

```
if 1 < score[x] and score[x] < 3:
```

Which checks that score[x] is between 1 and 3, exclusive. Then there is one final trick, Python allows you to write that in one single check as:

```
if 1 < score[x] < 3:
```

Although if you're comparing several ranges like this, you may want to change either of the `<`s to `<=`, because otherwise all your ranges will fail if `score[x]` is exactly one of the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples) to take care of this for you.  The example from the documentation can easily be modified for your case:

```
from bisect import bisect
from collections import Counter

def grade(score, breakpoints=[3,6], grades='PGE'):
    i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
    return grades[i]

for k,v in Counter(grade(i) for i in [1,2,3,4,514,35,65,80]).iteritems():
    print('Grade: {} # of Awards: {}'.format(k,v))
```

Here is how it looks when run with a sample:

```
>>> for k,v in Counter(grade(i) for i in [1,2,3,456,342,90]).iteritems():
...    print('Grade: {} # of Awards: {}'.format(k,v))
...
Grade: P # of Awards: 2
Grade: E # of Awards: 3
Grade: G # of Awards: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you want something like this:

```
if 1 < score[x] and score[x] <3:
        review[x] = poor
        p = p + 1
```

There should be expression on both sides of 'and' to be evaluated by if after anding the result.
so it evaluates (1 < score[x]) and (score[x] <3) separately and 'and' the result of both.